# GDI+ linear gradient strange behavior

Tags: c++, drawing, gdi+, linear-gradients, brush

I need to create a linear gradient brush to paint a surface with GDI+. On the input, I receive the following parameters:

```
Viewport rect:   x = 0, y = 0, width = 744.09448819f, height = 1052.3622047f
Fill rect:       x = 13.040037f, y = 17.478735f, width = 721.3703f, height = 1009.1535f
Gradient start:  x = 384.8, y = 611.46
Gradient stop:   x = 378.93, y = 474.96
Start color:     a = 255, r = 179, g = 221, b = 253 (between 0 and 255)
End color:       a = 255, r = 51, g = 102, b = 152  (between 0 and 255)
Matrix to apply: a = 7.7430985, b = 0, c = 0, d = 7.2926249, e = -2439.6639, f = -3446.2263
Wrap mode:       clamp
```

These values were extracted from a SVG file. When I open it with my browser, I get the following result:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7C-RwCTA9qaNnFsaGJpenlseGc

Now I try to draw the exact same gradient with GDI+. I use Embarcadero RAD Studio c++ builder to do that. I wrote the following code:

```cpp
void DrawGradient()
{
    std::auto_ptr<TBitmap> pBitmap(new TBitmap());
    pBitmap->Width  = 744.09448819f;
    pBitmap->Height = 1052.3622047f;
    pBitmap->Canvas->Brush->Color = clWhite;
    pBitmap->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0, 0, pBitmap->Width, pBitmap->Height));

    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(pBitmap->Canvas->Handle);

    Gdiplus::LinearGradientBrush brush(
                                       Gdiplus::PointF(384.8, 611.46),
                                       Gdiplus::PointF(378.93, 474.96),
                                       Gdiplus::Color(255, 179, 221, 253),
                                       Gdiplus::Color(255, 51, 102, 152)
                                      );

    Gdiplus::Matrix matrix(7.7430985, 0, 0, 7.2926249, -2439.6639, -3446.2263);
    brush.SetTransform(&matrix);

    graphics.FillRectangle(&brush, 13.040037f, 17.478735f, 721.3703f, 1009.1535f);

    pBitmap->SaveToFile(L"test.bmp");
}
```

However I get this result:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7C-RwCTA9qaU1BhSTJxay16Z00

Putting aside the question of clamping, for which I know that GDI + offers no simple solution (like e.g. putting the Gdiplus::WrapModeClamp in the SetWrapMode() function, that could be so easy for the users), the resulting drawing should at least be closer to the expected result, or I'm wrong?

Somebody can explain to me why I get a so different result?

**NOTE** I already tweaked all the parameters, I obtain just several variations of the same wrong result

**NOTE** The original SVG that I refer above can be obtained here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7C-RwCTA9qaYkNRQ3lJNC1fNmM

Regards